# Editor for firebug or 'how to embed a custom editor' in a firefox tab?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug, embedding

Firebug is great for javascript development, but doesn't allow to edit the code (the 'edit html' in the firebug is not usable, doesn't save the file and even if it did, it is just an plain text editor without any coloring).

I usually have my editor opened next to Firefox, but the constant switching feels aarrgh! To have the editor **inside Firefox** could be better. Does anyone know of some solution to embed my preferred editor inside a Firefox tab? Or are there better options to edit the javascript code semi-interactively? Perhaps some js plugin?

I found this for linux: http://mozplugger.mozdev.org/ but not sure if that would on Mac OS X.

Comment: To comment on my own question, the new dev release of firebug contains 'open with editor...' option inside the menu. Not exactly what i wanted, but might be very handy. Not sure if it was present in the release as of time of writing (1.5x)

Answer (score 0):

you'll obtain more success embeding  browser in IDE. The editor in browser never can provide an advanced usage and good user experience.